# Deduct coins when users ask for hint

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wanted to create a hint where it will prompt user whether user need a hint for the answers. 
If user wants a hint, it will display a hint and deduct 100 coins from users. I tried so many times but it still did not work.

```
 <a href="#hint" class="btn btn-info" id="hint" data-toggle="collapse" 
       onclick="Confirmation()">Hint</a>



 function Confirmation() {
    var retVal = confirm("Are you sure you want a hint");
    if (retVal == true) {
        <div id="hint" class="collapse">
          <span style=" border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;">Answer: A </span>
       </div>
      **//Not sure on how to deduct 100 coins**

        return true;
    }
    else {
        document.write("User does not want to continue!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the Confirmation() while your function is named getConfirmation()

Answer (score 0):

`onclick="Confirmation()"`

`function getConfirmation()`

`Confirmation` and `getConfirmation` are two different labels